# Calculate nth root?

Tags: objective-c, math

Is there a way to calculate the nth root of a double in objective-c?

I couldn't seem to find an appropriate function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the pow function:

```
pow(d, 1.0/n)
```

[image]

Comment: It might be wise to use an explicit float here `pow(d, 1.0/n)`, since otherwise it won't work with n as an integer.

Comment: This won't work for  odd numbered (e.g. cubic) roots and negative values - see my answer below.

Comment: Using an "explicit float" is unnecessary. Swift infers that `/` here means `Double`-division (because `pow` with a first argument of type `Double` requires a second argument of type `Double`), and therefore infers that `1` and `3` are also `Double`. If you replace `3` with a variable `n` of type `Int`, you get a compile-time error, regardless of whether the numerator is `1` or `1.0`.

Comment: @ericgu I suspect flo-von-der-uni used the word "and" rather than "nor" on purpose in his comment.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, the n-th root of x is x to the power of 1/n.

I have no idea what the syntax of objective-c would be, but basically you just want to use the power function with 1/n as the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

For odd numbered roots (e.g. cubic) and negative numbers, the result of the root is well defined and negative, but just using `pow(value, 1.0/n)` won’t work (you get back ’NaN’ - not a number).

So, use this instead:

```
int f = (value < 0 && (n % 2 == 1)) ? -1 : 1;
root = pow(value * f, 1.0/n) * f
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `#Math.h` macros file which I import when needed

`#define rootf(__radicand, __index) (powf(((float)__radicand),(1.0f/((float)__index))))`

So cubed root of 20 would be `rootf(20,3)`