# Correct way to find nth root using pow() in c++

Tags: c++

I have to find nth root of numbers that can be as large as 10^18, with n as large as 10^4.
I know using pow() we can find the nth roots using,

```
x = (long int)(1e-7 + pow(number, 1.0 / n))
```

But this is giving wrong answers on online programming judges, but on all the cases i have taken, it is giving correct results. Is there something wrong with this method for the given constraints 
Note: nth root here means the largest integer whose nth power is less than or equal to the given number, i.e., largest 'x' for which x^n <= number.
Following the answers, i know this approach is wrong, then what is the way i should do it?

Comment: Why on earth do you add 1e-7 and cast to integer ??

Comment: I should have mentioned the meaning of nth root here. Edited now. Without using it, it gives incorrent answers for cases like, cube root of 1000.

Comment: Even so, this is unnecessary before casting to integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate nth root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866998/calculate-nth-root)

Comment: `Without using it, it gives incorrent answers for cases like, cube root of 1000`  And by using it, it may throw correct answers off.  Anytime you're using adhoc fudge factors like adding `1e-7`, it is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Even double doesn't have enough precision to store 10000th root of 10^18. In such cases x will always be 0

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: don't you mean 1 ?

Comment: This question is less easy than it looks at first sight, because of the rounding errors. The critical cases are when `number` is a perfect n-th power.

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc using x = (long long int)(1e-7 + pow(10^18, 1.0/10000)) gives 1 which is right.

Comment: @AlexS: The linked question doesn't has any solution to my question. The only thing mentioned is using pow().

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: right. It would be nice to justify the value 1e-7 and check correctness in the whole domain.

Comment: Perhaps use the code you have to get an approximate value (that might be off by one) and check (using integer arithmetic) whether x-1, x or x+1 is the correct answer?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc How is 1.004 "too tiny" to store in a double?  1.004 ^ 10,000 = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 (roughly).

Comment: @ebyrob+Lưu Vĩnh Phúc: actually it's the integer part that matters, so any decimal can be wrong. Assuming n>1, 30 bits of mantissa are enough in the worst case (square root of 10^18). As soon as n>59, 0 bit is enough (as the answer will be 1!).

Comment: @YvesDaoust That was my point...  double can certainly do the job as it has 52 bits of mantissa already.  I guess I could have said: "double can store the difference between 10^9 and 10^6 just fine".  instead I answered the literal question posed by Lu'u: It can do exactly what he said it couldn't.  (store that specific root and it's value is roughly 1.004.  .004 being a very large difference in this case from 1.000)

Comment: @ebyrob: I wasn't contradicting you, on the opposite.

Comment: @ebyrob 1.004^10000 = 2.17334208581047... × 10^17 which is far from 10^18 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+1.004+^+10%2C000. OK maybe I'm wrong because I was thinking in the reverse direction. 10^(10000/18) is outside double's range and so is 10^(18/10000)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use

```
x = (long int)pow(number, 1.0 / n)
```

Given the high value of `n`, most answers will be 1.

UPDATE:

Following the OP comment, this approach is indeed flawed, because in most cases 1/n does not have an exact floating-point representation and the floor of the 1/n-th power can be off by one.

And rounding is not better solution, it can make the root off by one in excess.

Another problem is that values up to 10^18 cannot be represented exactly using double precision, whereas 64 bits ints do.

My proposal:

1) truncate the 11 low order bits of number before the (implicit) cast to double, to avoid rounding up by the FP unit (unsure if this is useful).

2) use the `pow` function to get an inferior estimate of the n-th root, let `r`.

3) compute the n-th power of `r+1` using integer arithmetic only (by repeated squaring).

4) the solution is `r+1` rather than `r` in case that the n-th power fits.

There remains a possibility that the FP  unit rounds up when computing 1/n, leading to a slightly too large result. I doubt that this "too large" can get as large as one unit in the final result, but this should be checked.

Comment: "Another problem is that values up to 10^18 cannot be represented exactly using double precision, whereas 64 bits ints do." Which is probably the goal of the problem: to make the programmer implement an nth root function using integral arithmetic.

Comment: @James: quite right. This is by no means trivial. But the title says `pow`.

Comment: Yes.  But if you read the question, the poster seems to be the one having decided to use `pow`.  The question he's trying to answer probably doesn't have that restriction, and probably expects him to work out how to find the nth root using integral arithmetic (which isn't too difficult if performance isn't an issue).

Comment: @James: "which isn't too difficult": I don't agree with that, I don't find it so straightforward (merely trying the n-th power of increasing integers is not acceptable). And using the `pow` function to quickly get a good estimate of the root isn't such a bad idea.

Comment: "Isn't too difficult" If performance isn't an issue.  A binary search will take at most 64 tries.  And calculating an integral power of an integer, in order to see whether you need to go up or down, is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @James: I am sure I'd get lost in the "details" like overflow handling.

Comment: Subtracting 10^-9 from 1/n would probably remove any chance of rounding up... (and shouldn't fudge the number too much as it'd be 5 orders of magnitude smaller than 1 / 10,000)  even 10^-7 would probably do since it's a spare 3 orders of magnitude, but it's likely applied in the wrong place in the question.  (to the result, rather than the input)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understood your problem.  All you want to do is raise a value, say *X*, to the reciprocal of a number, say *n* (i.e., find ⁿ√X̅), and round down.  If you then raise that answer to the *n*-th power, it will never be larger than your original *X*.  The problem is that the computer sometimes runs into rounding error.

```
#include <cmath>

long find_nth_root(double X, int n)
{
    long nth_root = std::trunc(std::pow(X, 1.0 / n));
    // because of rounding error, it's possible that nth_root + 1 is what we actually want; let's check
    if (std::pow(nth_root + 1, n) <= X) {
        return nth_root + 1;
    }
    return nth_root;
}
```

Of course, the original question was to find the largest integer, *Y*, that satisfies the equation *X ≤ Yⁿ*.  That's easy enough to write:

```
long find_nth_root(double x, int d)
{
    long i = 0;
    for (; std::pow(i + 1, d) <= x; ++i) { }
    return i;
}
```

This will probably run faster than you'd expect.  But you can do better with a binary search:

```
#include <cmath>

long find_nth_root(double x, int d)
{
    long low = 0, high = 1;
    while (std::pow(high, d) <= x) {
        low = high;
        high *= 2;
    }
    while (low != high - 1) {
        long step = (high - low) / 2;
        long candidate = low + step;

        double value = std::pow(candidate, d);
        if (value == x) {
            return candidate;
        }
        if (value < x) {
            low = candidate;
            continue;
        }
        high = candidate;
    }
    return low;
}
```

Comment: It will work for ranges that `std::pow` returns something reasonable.  If you need better results than that, you'll need to (1) reimplement `std::pow`, or (2) use a bignum library (with its own `pow`), or (3) use a different algorithm altogether (say, a simple binary search for the largest number that when raised to the `n`th power returns a value less than or equal to `X`).

Comment: The problem statement is `number` up to 10^18 and `n` up to 10^4. One can infer that this wasn't chosen innocently.

Answer (score 0):

I use this routine I wrote. It's the faster of the ones I've seen here. It also handles up to 64 bits. BTW, n1 is the input number.

```
for (n3 = 0; ((mnk) < n1) ; n3+=0.015625, nmrk++) {
   mk += 0.0073125;
   dad += 0.00390625;
   mnk = pow(n1, 1.0/(mk+n3+dad));
   mnk = pow(mnk, (mk+n3+dad));
}
```

Although not always perfect, it does come the closest.

Comment: This is not pseudocode. I just wanted to give this away without motioning my work MUAHA

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the **nth_root** with unsigned in C :

```c
// return a number that, when multiplied by itself nth times, makes N.
unsigned nth_root(const unsigned n, const unsigned nth) {
    unsigned a = n, c, d, r = nth ? n + (n > 1) : n == 1 ;
    for (; a < r; c = a + (nth - 1) * r, a = c / nth)
        for (r = a, a = n, d = nth - 1; d && (a /= r); --d);
    return r;
}
```

**Yes** it does not include `<math.h>`, example of output :

```
  24 == (int) pow(15625, 1.0/3)

  25 == nth_root(15625, 3)
   0 == nth_root(0, 0)
   1 == nth_root(1, 0)
   4 == nth_root(4096, 6)
  13 == nth_root(18446744073709551614, 17) // 64-bit 20 digits
  11 == nth_root(340282366920938463463374607431768211454, 37) // 128-bit 39 digits
```

The default guess is the variable **a**, set to **n**.